How to optimize the structure of the HEMO group
I have used the GAMESS program to try to optimize the structure of an iron complex with oxidation state +3 with porphyrin. I have doubts about whether the charge and the multiplicity assigned to the calculation system would be correct or not.
I have a problem and it is that my system does not manage to converge, so I leave you the input file for the calculation with GAMESS.
 $SYSTEM MEMDDI=400 MWORDS=200 $END
 $CONTRL DFTTYP=B3LYP RUNTYP=OPTIMIZE EXETYP=DEBUG SCFTYP=UHF
 ICHARG=1 MULT=6 $END
 $SCF DIRSCF=.TRUE. $END
 $STATPT NSTEP=1000 $END
 $BASIS GBASIS=N31 NGAUSS=6 NDFUNC=1 $END
 $DATA
Cluster/6-31G
C1
C          6.0    -9.061   -0.285   31.049
C          6.0    -8.796    4.146   29.062
C          6.0    -6.514    2.210   25.269
C          6.0    -7.556   -2.278   26.819
C          6.0    -9.160    1.075   30.862
C          6.0    -9.705    2.025   31.814
C          6.0    -9.631    3.244   31.268
C          6.0    -9.036    3.117   29.950
C          6.0   -10.101    4.558   31.924
C          6.0   -10.272    1.689   33.210
C          6.0   -11.769    1.425   33.101
C          6.0   -12.432    1.498   34.453
O          8.0   -13.665    1.258   34.532
O          8.0   -11.734    1.798   35.455
C          6.0    -8.127    4.016   27.865
C          6.0    -7.732    5.095   26.975
C          6.0    -7.109    4.543   25.920
C          6.0    -7.075    3.114   26.131
C          6.0    -8.027    6.590   27.236
C          6.0    -6.462    5.202   24.678
C          6.0    -6.112    6.490   24.606
C          6.0    -6.578    0.843   25.370
C          6.0    -5.946   -0.072   24.455
C          6.0    -6.207   -1.310   24.856
C          6.0    -7.035   -1.240   26.060
C          6.0    -5.100    0.308   23.220
C          6.0    -5.664   -2.528   24.085
C          6.0    -5.830   -3.764   24.530
C          6.0    -8.058   -2.188   28.108
C          6.0    -8.472   -3.293   28.959
C          6.0    -8.940   -2.648   30.271
C          6.0    -8.762   -1.230   30.091
C          6.0    -8.469   -4.804   28.640
C          6.0    -9.473   -3.343   31.540
C          6.0    -8.270   -3.853   32.334
C          6.0    -8.683   -4.276   33.720
O          8.0    -8.276   -5.386   34.159
O          8.0    -9.429   -3.506   34.379
N          7.0    -8.759    1.776   29.737
N          7.0    -7.707    2.817   27.318
N          7.0    -7.236    0.103   26.337
N          7.0    -8.248   -1.001   28.815
H          1.0   -10.841    4.374   32.523
H          1.0   -10.389    5.178   31.236
H          1.0    -9.369    4.949   32.426
H          1.0    -8.849    6.674   27.745
H          1.0    -8.122    7.054   26.389
H          1.0    -7.295    6.982   27.738
H          1.0    -4.433   -0.378   23.061
H          1.0    -4.658    1.157   23.379
H          1.0    -5.677    0.384   22.444
H          1.0    -8.332   -5.307   29.458
H          1.0    -7.754   -5.002   28.015
H          1.0    -9.320   -5.053   28.246
H          1.0    -5.710    6.839   23.795
H          1.0    -6.260    7.076   25.365
H          1.0    -5.478   -4.513   24.024
H          1.0    -6.304   -3.920   25.362
H          1.0   -11.919    0.550   32.711
H          1.0   -12.172    2.074   32.504
H          1.0   -10.107    2.423   33.822
H          1.0    -9.822    0.910   33.573
H          1.0    -7.596   -3.157   32.391
H          1.0    -7.865   -4.602   31.870
H          1.0   -10.061   -4.078   31.304
H          1.0    -9.994   -2.723   32.074
H          1.0    -9.211   -0.599   31.911
H          1.0    -9.110    4.991   29.289
H          1.0    -6.044    2.556   24.545
H          1.0    -7.570   -3.119   26.423
H          1.0    -6.300    4.644   23.901
H          1.0    -5.188   -2.386   23.252
Fe        26.0    -7.890    0.888   28.105
 $END


+1. Welcome to our community.
